# How to stop monodevelop add **-noconfig** compilation option?

Tags: mono, moq

I tried to compile this moq example on Mono 2.8.2, targeting .NET 3.5., with MonoDevelop 2.4.1

```
using System;
using Moq;

namespace moq_demo
{
    public interface IFoo
    {
        bool DoSomething(string n);
    }

    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
            mock.Setup(foo => foo.DoSomething("ping")).Returns(true);
        }
    }
}
```

I got 3 compile error:

> /home/rupert/Projects/moq_demo/moq_demo/Main.cs(36,36): Error CS1660: Cannot convert `lambda expression' to non-delegate type`System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>' (CS1660) (moq_demo)
>
> /home/rupert/Projects/moq_demo/moq_demo/Main.cs(30,30): Error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `Moq.Mock.Setup(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)' has some invalid arguments (CS1502) (moq_demo)
>
> /home/rupert/Projects/moq_demo/moq_demo/Main.cs(30,30): Error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert`anonymous method' expression to type `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>' (CS1503) (moq_demo)

I've completely no idea what does these means.  Anyone knows what might cause the problem?

---

**Edit**

I tried to compile it directly with command

> gmcs Main.cs /r:Moq.dll

and it compiled.  So it must be caused by some additional compile option introduced by MonoDevelop.  By export make file, I confirmed my guess.  This compile command

> gmcs -noconfig -codepage:utf8 -warn:4 -out:bin/Release/moq_demo.exe -target:exe './Main.cs' './AssemblyInfo.cs'      -r:System  -r:Moq.dll

will trigger the compile error.  By eliminating these options one by one, I found it's **-noconfig** that caused all the problem.

So the problem no became : How to stop monodevelop add **-noconfig** compilation option?

Comment: This builds and runs fine for me on mono 2.11 (trunk mono as of about a month ago) and mono 2.6.7.

Can you post more source?

Comment: I tried this - http://pastebin.com/rTNW5LSc Builds and runs fine.

Comment: Hey, thanks, I found the compile option that caused the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-noconfig` option means you must supply all the assembly references on the command line. Your compile error is because you must add a reference to `System.Core` in monodevelop to satisfy the lambda expression types you've used.

```
$ gmcs -noconfig test.cs -r:Moq.dll -r:System.dll -r:System.Core.dll
```

works for me.